# What should I use other than `javax.net.sampled` package to handle the audio streaming?

Tags: java, android, sockets, audio-streaming

I am trying to develop an app for audio conferencing between two android mobiles using socket programming. I managed to do that in java using `javax.net.sampled` package to handle the audio streaming. But this package is not available in android and I am using api 10. So What should I use other than `javax.net.sampled` package to handle the audio streaming?